# Using matlab to find Laplace transform

Tags: matlab

f(t) =  t*e^t when 0 <= t < 3

f(t) =  0 when 3 <= t

how to use Matlab to find Laplace transforms of functions which change according to different values of t

Comment: are you interested in numerical laplace transform or symbolic?

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB has a function called [laplace](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html?searchHighlight=laplace&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), and we can calculate it like:

```
syms x y
f = 1/sqrt(x);
laplace(f)
```

But it will be a very long code when we turn f(x) like this problem into `syms`. 
Indeed, we can do this by using `dirac` and `heaviside` if we have to. Nevertheless, we could use this instead:

```
syms t s
f=t*exp((1-s)*t);
F=int(f,t,0,3)
```

It is because:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a numerical implementation of the Laplace transform, you can download from Matlab's file exchange the following [Numerical Transform](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/60837-numerical-laplace-transform) and the [inverse transform](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39035-numerical-inverse-laplace-transform/) ...